# Http Get Request not getting any data

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, https, xamarin.forms

I have my Web Api on a production server online and working well in postman and in Xamarin forms so far until I needed to do a Get Request and does not return any data. Infact it stops at the `GetAsStringAsync` line and does not continue. Instead, it jumps out of the method and then nothing more.

Does any one know what the problem could be? I have checked and made sure my Internet is working and the Uri too.

This is where I am doing my Get in Xamarin forms:

```
public async Task<List<OfferModel>> AllOffers()
{
    var httpclient = new HttpClient();
    httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", Settings.AccessToken);
    //it does not continue after this line, it jumps out of the method instead
    var response = await httpclient.GetStringAsync(UrlConstants.offerurl);
    var data =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OfferModel(response);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: are there any exception or other error messages? I don't see the closing > in your 
var data = .... line. is that just a typo or are they missing?

Comment: are you sure the URL works from the device/emulator?  Testing it from your desktop does NOT mean that it is reachable from your mobile app.

Comment: @Jason the URL is working well from postman and it's reachable from the device. Haven't tried it in the emulator cos of WiFi issues.

Comment: @Sean the closing > was a typo. No error messages, it just leaves the method and then nothing happens.

Comment: The behavior you’re describing is the await never returns. If possible set a breakpoint at the other end and see if your call is reaching the remote server.

Comment: @Sean thanks. Yes it does not return anything in the await method. And what is the other end you talking about ?

Comment: The remote endpoint you are trying to reach. If you can debug that endpoint then you can see if the problem is that you can’t reach the endpoint or some other error. If you can’t debug the remote endpoint, try removing the async/await logic and see if you get a more detailed error.

Comment: @Sean I can't debug the endpoint. I have it on a remote server already. The http method GetStringAsync is an async method and won't even build if I don't have an async/await logic on it.

Comment: If you remove the await from GetStringSync you'll have to add .Result to the end of that line (ie GetStringAsync(...).Result).

Comment: @Sean, it worked perfectly okay and returned my json data when I took out the async/await scope. What do you think could have caused that ? And can I be able to use it without the scope in my application and won't cause blockage whatsoever?

Comment: without an error message I'd just guessing. MSDN Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_GetStringAsync_System_String_) say that call is nonblocking.

Comment: Hi, Have you solved?@Classyk

Comment: @Junior Jiang I was able to solve it by removing the async/await keyword from the method and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Classyk Great ! Remember to post answer .

Comment: In Xamarin i recommend to use async / await keywords in your requests, 
Because service requests may be take longer. So it is a cleaner job to wait for the result and keep the user in loader page.
Otherwise the user can think that the application is not working.

Comment: If the answer worked for you you have to mark as answer it about user rights.

Answer (score 1):

> Solution 1

Can you try access task via awaiter it may be wait until result when responded

```
    public class HttpHelperService
    {
                public async Task<List<OfferModel>> AllOffers()
                {
                    List<OfferModel> result;
                    string responseBody;
                    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", Settings.AccessToken);
                            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(UrlConstants.offerurl)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OfferModel>>(response);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            result = null;
                        }
                        return result;
                    }
                }
        }
```

> Solution 2

```
public class MyPage : ContentPage
{
//Here is your page constructor
    public MyPage()
    {
       GetServices(); //--> call here without awaiter
    }
}

//Here is your awaiter method
    private async void GetServices()
    {
       LoadingPopupService.Show();
       var result = await HttpService.AllOffers();
        LoadingPopupService.Hide();
    }

//Here is your service.
    public async Task<List<OfferModel>> AllOffers()
    {
        var httpclient = new HttpClient();
        httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", Settings.AccessToken);
        var response = await httpclient.GetStringAsync(UrlConstants.offerurl);
        var data =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OfferModel(response);
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: thanks. I will take a make these changes to my code and see if it works and give you a feedback .

Comment: My solution was to this problem:1. A main method to get datas from services. 2. An awaiter method to asynchronusly getting data by showing a loader to user.
3. Page's constructor. You can call directly 2. method in constructor without await. It will be wait getting data.

Comment: Okay Batuhan. I see them and I will check them out and try them

Comment: If your issue has been completed with answer up, you can mark as completed my answer.