# Xamarin WebAPI call not running - no exception raised

Tags: xamarin.forms, webapi

I have the following method in Xamarin that makes an API call that returns a list of Items. When I start Visual Studio and run it returns a string of JSON with the information I expect it to. However when I run it several times and more often than not it hits the string returnedJson = await client.GetStringAsync line then just breaks out of the method, returning nothing.

I dont think its related to restarting Visual Studio, because sometimes after it not working several times it will work once again then stop again.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ItemModel>> GetItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false)
    {
        var baseAddr = new Uri("https://www.domain.co.uk");

        var client = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = baseAddr
        };

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Settings.ApiToken);

        // NOW PROTECTED
        try
        {
            string returnedJson = await client.GetStringAsync("/api/Items/Index");

            var convert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ItemModel>>(returnedJson);

            return convert;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return null;

    }
```

The WebAPI method -

```
 [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<List<ItemModel>> Index()
    {
        return await itemService.Get();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried postman ? Does it work on every request ?

Comment: It does work 100% of the time in Postman yes

Comment: Try to use `HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(UrlConstants.offerurl)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();` instead , refer the similar thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55326677/http-get-request-not-getting-any-data